# Question about a confusing sentence structure

Tags: grammar, meaning, sentence-construction, sentence-structure

> *The touch of a cluster of leaves revolved it slowly*, ***tracing***,
>   *like the leg of compass*, ***a thin red circle in the water***. 
>   (Context: "It" is a laden mattress that carries the dead body of
>   Gastsby and it is moving down the pool.) (Great Gastby, novel by F. Scott Fitzgerald)

I don't understand the structure of this sentence. Is the second part of the sentence a reduced relative clause? or a absoluete phrase? As far as I understand, the second part is defining the action of the "ladden mattress"
after the touch which is "tracing a thin red circle in the water" .

Comment: No, its a gerund participial clause functioning as a supplementary adjunct. It contains the further supplement "like the leg of a compass".

Comment: Is it defining "the touch" or "mattress" ?

Comment: It has the whole preceding clause as 'anchor' (its antecedent).